# InDesign: how to fix the position of anchored objects

Tags: adobe-indesign, formatting

How to fix the position of anchored object. It is overlapping on the paragraph after applying a paragraph style.

Comment: You can't merely move move it with the Selection tool?

Comment: Can you please include an image of what you mean? As it is, it's pretty unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Are you talking about an anchored object with text wrap applied that doesn’t apply to the paragraph the object is anchored in? If that’s what you’re referring to, there is no way around it—text wrap does not apply to the paragraph an anchored object is anchored in, and there is no way to make it do so. Unfortunately. It’s one of the most frustrating shortcomings about InDesign, but fixing it would require essentially rethinking and rewriting how anchored objects work altogether, which is not likely to happen.

Answer (score 1):

This is too broad to give any specific reply, but a broad answer would be you have lots of options to position an anchored object:

- select the object
- right click and choose 'Anchored Object → Options'
- play with the settings, some of which are self explanatory, for the rest see the [official docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/anchored-objects.html)

Comment: I am expecting script that will do that task